# Combine 4 multidimensional arrays into one array while maintaining the original dimensions - Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 4 multidimensional arrays, each with dimensions of nrow=50 ncol=100. Each array consists of mostly zeros, but does contain lengths of float data (non-zeros). Also, across all 4 arrays, the position of non-zero data is always a zero in that same position in the other arrays. I've therefore been trying to overlay the arrays, but have been highly unsuccessful! I'm very new to Python.

My attempts to keep the dimensions the same also end up with nrows 4 times the original.

Comment: Please post what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions of the 4 arrays is the same and *position of non-zero data is always a zero in that same position in the other arrays* as you said you can simply add the arrays together, i.e.

```
combined = ar1 + ar2 + ar3 + ar4
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple, I was overthinking it! This works, thanks again.